# "Which" followed by "although"

Tags: which-that, parentheticals

I'm curious to hear some thoughts on whether this sentence is grammatically acceptable.
Although it reads fine in my head, I feel a bit uncomfortable placing *although* after the word *which*.

> [...] our process which, although terribly undefined, had sufficient similarities to [...]

Comment: Is 'terribly' the pure bleached intensifier here? 'Very undefined' seems to push the bounds a bit. It may be correct, but it takes a lot of analysing.

Comment: _Which_ is the subject of _had_, so the adverbial clause _although .. undefined_ is sitting right where adverbs go -- before the main verb when there's no auxiliaries.

Comment: The clause between the commas is a "parenthetical", and can be deleted without "breaking" the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

*Although terribly undefined* is a *[parenthetical clause](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/8-types-of-parenthetical-phrases/)* (more specifically a ***free modifier***), no doubt, grammatically acceptable. Delimitation by commas does help, though the phrase could stand without them, too.

> In essence, a *parenthetical* is just a phrase that is *not essential* to the rest of the sentence. However, just because it isn’t essential does not mean that it isn’t important. When used correctly, ***a parenthetical can add crucial new information to a sentence without disrupting the flow***. (*[University of Nevada, Reno](https://www.unr.edu/writing-speaking-center/student-resources/writing-speaking-resources/parenthetical-phrases#:%7E:text=In%20essence%2C%20a%20parenthetical%20is,sentence%20without%20disrupting%20the%20flow.)*)

But it is true that *which although* can sound a bit of a mouthful. In such cases, using the more seamless ***though*** can help:

> our process which, ***though*** terribly undefined, had sufficient similarities to...

Both *although* and *though* can be used to introduce reduced clauses. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/although-or-though))

Comment: Though the first block quote goes on to spell this out, 'In essence, a parenthetical is a phrase that is not essential to _ensure the grammaticality of_ the rest of the sentence' is more felicitous.

Answer (score 0):

That comma saves the meaning - it separates your subordinate clause nicely.

Comment: The meaning would not change without the commas.

Comment: @RegDwigнt The meaning might not change without the commas but it would become much less clear.